# Que tipo de ponteiro é esse?

Tags: c++, string

Tenho o Seguinte Código:

```
int main() {
    string animal = "cabrito";
    string &pn = animal;
    
    pn = "bode";
    
    cout << animal << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Que gera a saída:

> bode

Eu fiquei muito confuso com esse código, o endereço de pn recebe a váriavel animal e consegue modificá-la como se fosse um ponteiro, Como assim?

Tenho também este código que converte uma string para maiúsculo:

```
int main() {
    string animal = "cabrito";
    
    for (auto &letra: animal) letra = toupper(letra);
    
    
    cout << animal << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Com a saída:

> CABRITO

Basicamente como no primeiro código só que altera caractere por caractere da string, tentei fazer isso mas dessa vez com um ponteiro e ficou assim:

```
int main() {
    string animal = "cabrito";
    
    for (auto *letra: &animal) *letra = toupper(*letra);
    
    
    cout << animal << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Fiz isso de vários outros jeitos usando o Ponteiro mas nenhum funcionou.

Afinal oque esse código:

```
string &pn = animal;
pn = "cabrito";
```

Está fazendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código:

```
string &pn = animal;
pn = "cabrito";
```

Não é necessariamente um ponteiro da forma que conhece normalmente em C (recomendo que leia sobre [referências em C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)). Isso **é uma referência**. Veja que o "&" está no lado ESQUERDO da declaração da variável e não do lado direito como fazemos em ponteiros para resgatar seu endereço em memória:

```
std::string *pn = &animal;
```

Por mais que um ponteiro também seja uma referência, essa sintaxe é uma forma de "apelidar" a referência ao invés de ter que usar um ponteiro:

Com um ponteiro faríamos:

```
std::string *pn = &animal;
std::cout << *pn << std::endl;
```

Com uma referência:

```
std::string &pn = animal;
std::cout << pn << std::endl;
```

Mas ainda se trata da mesma região de memória. Por isso que no seu primeiro código:

```
int main() {
    string animal = "cabrito";
    string &pn = animal;
    
    pn = "bode";
    
    cout << animal << endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Resultou em `"bode"`. **O `&pn` é uma referência a variável `animal`, por isso seu valor foi alterado**.